# MySQL my.cnf recommended settings MariaDB 10.2

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am a beginner managing a server and I have a problem after upgrading from MySQL 5.7 to MariaDB 10.2. Performance usage is very high: 191%. Can somebody help optimize values in my.cnf for a database server with the following specifications:

```
> Architecture:          x86_64
> 
> CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
> 
> Byte Order:            Little Endian
> 
> CPU(s):                2
> 
> On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
> 
> Thread(s) per core:    1
> 
> Core(s) per socket:    1
> 
> Socket(s):             2
> 
> NUMA node(s):          1
> 
> Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
> 
> CPU family:            6
> 
> Model:                 79
> 
> Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
> 
> Stepping:              1
> 
> CPU MHz:               2199.998
> 
> BogoMIPS:              4399.99
> 
> Virtualization:        VT-x
> 
> Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
> 
> Virtualization type:   full
> 
> L1d cache:             32K
> 
> L1i cache:             32K
> 
> L2 cache:              4096K
> 
> L3 cache:              16384K
> 
> NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
```

and MySQLTuner:

```
> >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.14 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
> 
>  >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
> 
>  >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
> 
> [--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
> 
> [OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.2.21-MariaDB
> 
> [OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
> 
> -------- Log file Recommendations ----------------------------------------------
> -------------------- [--] Log file: /var/lib/mysql/mvpiot.novalocal.err(513K)
> 
> [OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/mvpiot.novalocal.err exists
> 
> [OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/mvpiot.novalocal.err is readable.
> 
> [OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/mvpiot.novalocal.err is not empty
> 
> [OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/mvpiot.novalocal.err is smaller than 32
> Mb
> 
> [!!] /var/lib/mysql/mvpiot.novalocal.err contains 1146 warning(s).
> 
> [!!] /var/lib/mysql/mvpiot.novalocal.err contains 2355 error(s).
> 
> [--] 37 start(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/mvpiot.novalocal.err
> 
> 
> [--] 1) 2019-01-12  8:25:46 140431271381184 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld:
> ready for connections.
> 
> [--] 2) 2019-01-12  7:29:03 140574858127552 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld:
> ready for connections.
> 
> [--] 3) 2019-01-11 18:39:26 140560611846336 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld:
> ready for connections. [--] 4) 2019-01-11 17:00:17 140623437183168
> [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. [--] 5) 2019-01-11
> 16:30:08 140674500737216 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for
> connections. [--] 6) 2019-01-11 14:55:17 140065307875520 [Note]
> /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. [--] 7) 2019-01-11 13:34:41
> 140588138420416 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. [--]
> 8) 2019-01-11 13:01:12 139932833945792 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready
> for connections. [--] 9) 2019-01-11 12:27:23 140694443542720 [Note]
> /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. [--] 10) 2019-01-11 12:08:55
> 139655472789696 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. [--] 9
> shutdown(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/mvpiot.novalocal.err [--] 1)
> 2019-01-10 18:03:26 139706578528000 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown
> complete [--] 2) 2019-01-10 17:48:26 140143107737344 [Note]
> /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete [--] 3) 2019-01-10 17:45:56
> 140094187407104 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete [--] 4)
> 2019-01-10 17:42:51 139985407059712 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown
> complete [--] 5) 2019-01-10 17:26:12 140542010558208 [Note]
> /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete [--] 6) 2019-01-10 17:26:09
> 140119564142336 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete [--] 7)
> 2019-01-10 13:42:59 140154423613184 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown
> complete [--] 8) 2019-01-10  9:21:20 140596763801344 [Note]
> /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete [--] 9) 2019-01-10  9:21:18
> 139833937012480 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
> 
> 
> -------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM
> +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE
> 
> [--] Data in Aria tables: 192.0K (Tables: 6)
> 
> [--] Data in MyISAM tables: 15.5M (Tables: 85)
> 
> [--] Data in InnoDB tables: 140.7M (Tables: 87)
> 
> [OK] Total fragmented tables: 0
> 
> 
> -------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
> 
> [OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
> 
> 
> -------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
> 
> [OK] All database users have passwords assigned
> 
> [!!] There is no basic password file list!
> 
> 
> -------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined
> 
> 
> -------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [--] Up for: 1h 26m 8s (432K q [83.607 qps], 20K conn, TX: 710M, RX:
> 32M)
> 
> [--] Reads / Writes: 97% / 3%
> 
> [--] Binary logging is disabled
> 
> [--] Physical Memory     : 3.9G
> 
> [--] Max MySQL memory    : 2.9G
> 
> [--] Other process memory: 0B
> 
> [--] Total buffers: 672.0M global + 4.5M per thread (500 max threads)
> 
> [--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
> 
> [--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
> 
> [OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 1016.7M (25.74% of installed RAM)
> 
> [OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 2.9G (74.41% of installed RAM)
> 
> [OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible
> with memory available
> 
> [OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/432K)
> 
> [OK] Highest usage of available connections: 15% (76/500)
> 
> [OK] Aborted connections: 0.39%  (82/20849)
> 
> [!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for
> each new connection and can reduce performance
> 
> [!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
> 
> [OK] Query cache efficiency: 39.5% (237K cached / 602K selects)
> 
> [OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
> 
> [OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 129 sorts)
> 
> [!!] Joins performed without indexes: 23
> 
> [OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 21% (296 on disk / 1K total)
> 
> [OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (76 created / 20K connections)
> 
> [OK] Table cache hit rate: 94% (319 open / 339 opened)
> 
> [OK] Open file limit used: 1% (188/10K)
> 
> [OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (7K immediate / 7K locks)
> 
> 
> -------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [--] Performance schema is disabled.
> 
> [--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
> 
> [--] Sys schema is installed.
> 
> 
> -------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
> 
> [--] Thread Pool Size: 2 thread(s).
> 
> [--] Using default value is good enough for your version
> (10.2.21-MariaDB)
> 
> 
> -------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [!!] Key buffer used: 18.4% (24M used / 134M cache)
> 
> [OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/9.4M
> 
> [OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 99.4% (748K cached / 4K reads)
> 
> [!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 1.3% (255K cached / 3K writes)
> 
> 
> -------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [--] InnoDB is enabled.
> 
> [--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
> 
> [OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
> 
> [!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/140.7M
> 
> [!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (75 %):
> 48.0M * 2/128.0M should be equal 25%
> 
> [OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
> 
> [--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool
> Instance(s)
> 
> [OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with
> Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
> 
> [OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (532580940 hits/ 532588160
> total)
> 
> [!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 51.86% (13396 hits/ 25832 total)
> 
> [OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 12436 writes)
> 
> 
> -------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [--] AriaDB is enabled.
> 
> [OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/96.0K
> 
> [!!] Aria pagecache hit rate: 79.6% (1K cached / 302 reads)
> 
> 
> -------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [--] TokuDB is disabled.
> 
> 
> -------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [--] XtraDB is disabled.
> 
> 
> -------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [--] Galera is disabled.
> 
> 
> -------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> [--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
> 
> [--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
> 
> [--] Binlog format: MIXED
> 
> [--] XA support enabled: ON
> 
> [--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
> 
> [--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
> 
> [--] This is a standalone server
> 
> 
> -------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> General recommendations:
> 
>     Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/mvpiot.novalocal.err file
> 
>     Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/mvpiot.novalocal.err file
> 
>     MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
> 
>     Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
> 
>     Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
> 
>     Performance schema should be activated for better diagnostics
> 
>     Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: https://bit.ly/2TcGgtU
> 
> Variables to adjust:
> 
>     query_cache_size (=0)
> 
>     query_cache_type (=0)
> 
>     join_buffer_size (> 1.0M, or always use indexes with JOINs)
> 
>     performance_schema = ON enable PFS
> 
>     innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 140.7M) if possible.
> 
>     innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

If anyone has an optimized my.cnf, can you give it to me?

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis and suggestions will be provided.

Comment: Please also post on pastebin.com complete content of /var/lib/mysql/mvpiot.novalocal.err  for review.

Comment: Can you disable the Hypervisor?  You may find less thrashing of activities and allow more productive processing to complete quicker.

Comment: With 2 CPU's in your server, it is possible you could see 200% busy.  Divide CPU busy / CPU's for relative % busy.  If you had 800% busy on a 12 CPU system, 800 /12 = 66% busy.

Comment: Any interest in posting Additional information requested on Jan 12, 2019 at 15:02?  Without data, it is hard to understand what your MySQL instance is doing with the resources that are available.

Comment: I can not see that you have posted your my.cnf, so no one could optimize it for you.  Even if you will post your my.cnf and other requested information for analysis, it would be unusual for anyone to 'edit' your my.cnf and send it to you.  This type of activity is usually best done by the person managing the system.  And you do not want to acquire any problem by using something from outside your environment that has the potential of causing harm to your system.

Answer (score 2):

How is "performance usage" measured?

The main tunable is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  It should be about 70% of *available* RAM.  The other things in my.cnf should not be changed without first understanding the situation.  (The 128MB default is OK until your table get a bunch bigger.)

High CPU usage is almost always caused by lack of an optimal `INDEX` and/or poor formulation of some `SELECT`.  Find the naughty queries and let's work on them.  If you need help finding them, see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) on the slowlog.

You have a lot of MyISAM tables; consider converting them to InnoDB.  Tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb)

For NUMA, see my notes [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory#numa).

I repeat; You can't tune your way out of performance issues.

Comment: But why i use mysql 5.7 Performance CPU slower mariadb 10.2.

Comment: 5.7 and 10.2 have differences in their Optimizers.  I think we need to look at the 'worst' queries and figure out what the differences are, and how to work around them.

Comment: @huynhphong  The size of your innodb tables is less than 500M today, no need to WASTE 70% of available RAM on innodb_buffer_pool_size.  You only have 4G to start with.  1G will be fine until your data size grows as reported by MySQLTuner.pl.

Answer (score 0):

The best performance tune is to let Mariadb do it initially itself, comment out as many variables and restart - leave them there just comment them out with the #

This answer was written from a CentOS 7 perspective, and the Original Poster OS - not mentioned - may be different

Also you should consider upgrading to Mariadb 10.3 first.  It has changes that are better at memory management over 10.2 even and then strip down the my.cnf file FIRST, restart Mariadb, and Mariadb will self configure for what it thinks are the best settings - then run MySQLtuner.  See if the performance issue goes down.

Then read the start up log of Mariadb for how it is configuring itself for clues.

Make sure you are running as new a version of mysqltuner as possible, it supports Mariadb 10.3 - you can " yum install mysqltuner " and the the epel repo will deliver it to you.  Needless to say Mariadb is the default database currently shipping in CentOS 7

Some my.cnf variables are depreciated in 10.3 over 10.2 even and silently configure to a default value automatically per the machine and memory constraints Mariadb is running on.  If it does not restart - the startup log may tell of a depreciated variable and simply remove it from the my.cnf - and usually it will start.

Read the MySQLtuner suggestions with a grain of salt - carefully - ***they are NOT always the best thing to do.***

As said previously by others, MyISAM tables are not normally that to get the best performance with.  The default engine is now INNODB. Conversion of databases should be as simple as an ALTER TABLE command run from a script  - but see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/  some issues of why to convert are found here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970420/how-much-faster-is-myisam-compared-to-innodb

There are scripts about for how to do it like  a few here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856435/how-to-convert-all-tables-from-myisam-into-innodb

If you use phpMyadmin it will be even more simple.  phpMyadmin can be installed via yum also, but initial configuration is tricky depending on your web server

Mariadb 10.1 and 10.2 have a few issues that are greatly improved in 10.3.  It was discovered the hard way just how much trying to manually configure can add performance problems and take you actually backwards.  See my post at [SOLUTION - OOM Killer was killing mariadb every hour or so](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186993/solution-oom-killer-was-killing-mariadb-every-hour-or-so)

For instance Mariadb 10.1 installed and usually installs shared library files with Perconna server and uses the Xtradb engine instead of INNODB.  That is a long story not for the faint of heart or discussion here.  Depending on how your 10.2 was installed you may or may not have the shared Percona-server libraries files, but 10.3 no longer needs them at all.

Remember also even though Mariadb was a fork from MySQL 5.5 commands and variables are similar but often are different by a very slight amount like a dash maybe instead of an underscore and et cetera pay close attention and do not mix the Mariadb commands with MySQL commands - and if you scour the web for more help - be very careful to see that others do not do so for you in an attempt to help

There is no such thing as an "Optimized my.cnf" because Mariadb analyzes the machine it sees to configure itself under the scenes when it boots - which is why you should consider a naked my.cnf first and to enable the performance schema - or strip it from being disabled

10.3 launches now in even less memory than 10.2 and is faster that can be a big deal on a lower memory or single processor machine

See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/changes-improvements-in-mariadb-103/ for differences and improvements

Upgrade to 10.3 from 10.2 is not as difficult as it appears - and you do not need to uninstall all of 10.2 mariadb first - if you are using a Linux version that is an RPM type like Fedora or RHEL, CentOS 7 etc.  If not the below will not apply. Fedora and other rpm distros have their own update from a repository command

Stop Mariadb.  Simply change the repo to 10.3, in yum then run " yum update " - it will fail on Mariadb 10.3 server.  Yum remove or rpm erase server and then run yum update again and it will install the 10.3 server.  You will not loose data or databases - but of course back them up first just in case.  start Mariadb. 
 Then run mysql_upgrade   See also https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/upgrading-from-mysql-to-mariadb/

Mariadb 10.3 is the best version so far of Mariadb and time is better spent working with it than on 10.2